# Select Case with OR

Tags: vba

I'm trying to set up a conditional formatting where if the value in my cell doe not equal to item1 or item2 or item3 and so on then it would highlight it. The code is highlighting my cell even though the value is equal to one of the items. So pretty much I have a list of items that could be chosen but if the value does not equal one of the items in the list then it would highlight it. Here is my current code:

```
Dim item1 As Double, item2 As Double
Dim item3 As Double, item4 As Double
Dim item5 As Double, item6 As Double
Dim item7 As Double, item8 As Double
Dim item9 As Double, item10 As Double
Dim item11 As Double, item12 As Double

Dim material As Range

Dim C As Range

item1 = Me.Range("l5")
item2 = Me.Range("m5")
item3 = Me.Range("n5")
item4 = Me.Range("o5")
item5 = Me.Range("p5")
item6 = Me.Range("q5")
item7 = Me.Range("r5")
item8 = Me.Range("l7")
item9 = Me.Range("m7")
item10 = Me.Range("n7")
item11 = Me.Range("o7")
item12 = Me.Range("p7")

Set material = Intersect(Target, Me.Range("d24:d109"))

Application.EnableEvents = False
If Not material Is Nothing Then

    For Each C In material.Cells
       v = C.Value
       If Len(v) > 0 Then
           Select Case v
               Case Is <> item1 Or item2 Or item3 Or item4 Or item5 Or item6 Or item7 Or item8 Or item9 Or item10 Or item11 Or item12: newcolor = 3
           End Select
       Else
           newcolor = xlNone
       End If
        C.Interior.ColorIndex = newcolor
    Next C
End If
Application.EnableEvents = True
```

Comment: Your case statement is reading as "If v Does not Equal Item 1, Or v Equals Item 2, Or v Equals Item 3....". You can use commas to represent Or in Case. So do something like "Case Is <> Item1, Is <> Item2...". You may also want to just do multiple case lines for this, with nothing in the body of the conditional.

Comment: I originally had it case by case but it didn't work. Just tried it using "Case is <> Item1, is <> Item2, ...." and the results are the same as before.

Comment: SO isn't a discussion forum, nor a "hold my hand until my code works" site. Please do not edit your question in response to answers, and **make an effort** to debug your code.

Comment: Why do you think I'm on here? Obviously I've tried and got no where. If you're not helping then why even comment.

Answer (score 1):

Comma separated:

```
Case Is <> item1, item2, item3, item4, item5, item6, item7, item8, _
           item9, item10, item11, item12
```

But it's probably better to use a different data structure so that you don't need to keep adding `item` variables:

```
Dim coll as New Collection

coll.Add Me.Range("l5").Value2
coll.Add Me.Range("m5").Value2
coll.Add Me.Range("n5").Value2
coll.Add Me.Range("o5").Value2
coll.Add Me.Range("p5").Value2
coll.Add Me.Range("q5").Value2
coll.Add Me.Range("r5").Value2
coll.Add Me.Range("l7").Value2
coll.Add Me.Range("m7").Value2
coll.Add Me.Range("n7").Value2
coll.Add Me.Range("o7").Value2
coll.Add Me.Range("p7").Value2
```

And then use a function like described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44055463/check-if-item-exists-in-collection-with-application-match-in-vba/44055984#44055984) to test whether the value exists in the collection.

```
If Len(v) > 0 Then
    If Not colItmExists(coll, v) Then
        'Do something, or not...
    End If
```

Function:

```
Function colItmExists(col As Collection, itm) As Boolean
    Dim i, ret As Boolean
    For i = 1 To col.Count
        If col(i) = itm Then
            ret = True
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
    colItmExists = ret
End Function
```

Comment: If youre going with a Collection.Exists kind of method, you would be better off using a Scripting.Dictionary. A bit more work (CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")) but more effective overall.

Comment: @BrandonBarney Yes that's another option of course. I do use dictionaries extensively (and almost never use `Collection`) and [I often recommend them](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=user%3a1467082%20Scripting.Dictionary) here :) It's a judgement call in many cases, new users may prefer the intellisense with the native collection object but the dict's few methods are easy enough to commit to memory with little practice. Note also that Dictionaries cannot be used on Mac OS.

Comment: I was not aware that Dicts weren't available for Mac. Good to know! For a beginner a collection certainly makes sense, but in the case of OP's task it will increase lagtime given that he is looping through cells (innately power intensive) and then would be looping through the collection.

Comment: The entirety of the `Scripting.Runtime` library is not available in Mac @BrandonBarney -- that includes `FileSystemObject`, `File`, `Folder`, `TextStream` classes, among others :)  As far as optimization is concerned, there's nothing in *this* code that would require it (the ranges being used are so small that any differences in execution time would be negligible) :)

Comment: I tend to be more focused on not teaching the bad habits in the first place (if it can be avoided). Certainly it would be a negligible effect in this case, but should the project resize to 10 or 20 thousand rows, he will certainly feel it. In the end though, there is nothing wrong with the collection approach. It still solves the problem (and teaches him something new).

Comment: @BrandonBarney you could also use a `System.Collections.ArrayList` which has a `Contains` method or even the `Range.Find` :) but a `Collection` is an often-used class and the preferred way to check for existence in such an object is brute force iteration. Also, note that the call to `CreateObject` is expensive relative to using early-bound `As New Dictionary` (in my observations on 100,000 queries the dict becomes nearly as slow as the collection, whereas it can be 50% faster if using early-bound).

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this. The method is still somewhat inffective (since you are looping through cells), but it should work for your needs.

The methodology behind this is simple, if the cell value matches one of the existing criteria then do nothing. If it doesn't match any of them it will default to Case Else where it will set NewColor to 3.

The other thing worth noting is NewColor was never being reset to xlNone in your original version. This could cause the issue (since it was only being returned to xlNone when the len of the cell was 0.

Finally, I cleaned up code names and structure a bit. Try to make variable names more descriptive, and fully qualify everything (don't rely on `Double foo = bar.Range("baz")` since this will inevitably trip you up).

```
Sub Reformat()
Dim TargetRange As Range
Set TargetRange = Intersect(Target, Me.Range("d24:d109"))

Application.EnableEvents = False
Dim cell As Range
Dim NewColor As Variant
If Not material Is Nothing Then
    For Each cell In material.Cells
        If Len(cell.value) > 0 Then
            Select Case cell.value
                Case Is = Me.Range("L5").value
                Case Is = Me.Range("M5").value
                Case Is = Me.Range("N5").value
                Case Is = Me.Range("O5").value
                Case Is = Me.Range("P5").value
                Case Is = Me.Range("Q5").value
                Case Is = Me.Range("R5").value
                Case Is = Me.Range("L7").value
                Case Is = Me.Range("M7").value
                Case Is = Me.Range("N7").value
                Case Is = Me.Range("O7").value
                Case Is = Me.Range("P7").value
                Case Else
                    NewColor = 3
            End Select
        Else
            NewColor = xlNone
        End If
        cell.Interior.ColorIndex = NewColor
        NewColor = xlNone
    Next cell
End If
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Tried the code, and it appears to stop the highlighting completely. I've entered values outside of the cases and nothing happened.

Comment: Try stepping through the code (F8) to see what is happening. It should show it going through the Select Case loop.

Comment: Also, just in case, are you certain that the values match exactly? As far as VBA is concerned, doubles are fairly precise. Something like `.012911111111 = .0129` would return False.

Comment: When I hit F8, it highlights "Set TargetRange = Intersect(Target, Me.Range("d24:d109"))" and gives me a Run-Time Error - '424' - Object Required.

Comment: You need to change 'Me' to your actual worksheet. In my example I just stuck with your original code (I am guessing you had this code in a Worksheet_Change event of some sort?). Try defining the sheet. Something like `Dim TargetWorksheet as Worksheet: Set TargetWorksheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("SheetName")`

Comment: Brandon, please see the original post for the current code provided by you. It is still giving me a run-time error after adding the worksheet. And yes, the original code was in "Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)".

Comment: Your reference to `Worksheets("Componentlog")` is unqualified. Also, you will run into an issue since `Target` doesn't have a value (if you are running it as a standalone sub, and not as part of the worksheet change event). You'll want to learn how to step through the code and check for these issues (the immediate, locals, and watches window are lifesavers) since the error you are getting is one of the simpler errors you will encounter. You'll want to develop your abilities to debug these issues.

Comment: For now though, change how you set the target range. I would suggest something like `Set TargetRange ws.Range("D24:D109")`. It is poor form to hardcode the range in this manner, but for your purposes it will get you started. I can't stress enough the importance of walking through the problem using the windows mentioned above, and testing variables. You may also want to consider providing a copy of your worksheet so we can test it out.

Comment: Does it make a difference if the code was put under "Private Sub Worksheet_Change"?

Comment: Yes, since `Target` is an argument of the worksheet change events, and as a result `Target` would have a value. Run as a standalone sub, `Target` would never be declared. I also highly recommend `Option Explicit` at the top of all code modules.

Comment: Brandon, how do i share my workbook with you? Thanks.

Comment: You should be able to upload a copy of your workbook somewhere online (dropbox, or some other kind of sharing platform) and then upload a hyperlink to the document through your original post. Be sure that you arent sharing any confidential information though. I dont need the actual data. I just need a proof of concept kind of deal.

Comment: You need to share a link to the file, not a link to your dropbox. That link just brings me to my dropbox.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/b23393wfftit8ol/TODAY%20Component%20Log%2052317.xlsm?dl=0

Comment: @Sid.T. Please ensure you have set `Application.EnableEvents = True` and try your macro again. It works just fine for me.

Comment: Brandon, how does it work for you? Right now if I entered random numbers in column D, the code highlights it red. The idea is to highlight only values that are not listed in the cases.

Answer (score 0):

I think I *finally* tracked down the issue. Worth noting, before I explain, that you will want to try stepping through your code in the future. Breakpoints, 'Debug.Print' and F8 make a tremendous difference.

In this case, your roll ID's are different from your input values. Your roll Id in L7 is `70030908` note the whitespaces on either side. If I do 'Debug.Print ws.Range("L7").Value = 70030908` I get False. This is because, while the two look mostly like the same number, they aren't the same. Again, note the whitespaces on either side of the first number. To solve this, use explicit type conversion:

```
Dim TargetRange As Range
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Componentlog")
Set TargetRange = Intersect(Target, ws.Range("D24:D" & ws.Rows.Count))

Application.EnableEvents = False
Dim cell As Range
Dim NewColor As Variant

If Not TargetRange Is Nothing Then
    For Each cell In TargetRange.Cells
        If Len(cell.Value) > 0  and IsNumeric(cell.Value) Then
            Select Case CDbl(cell.Value)
                Case CDbl(ws.Range("L5").Value)
                Case CDbl(ws.Range("M5").Value)
                Case CDbl(ws.Range("N5").Value)
                Case CDbl(ws.Range("O5").Value)
                Case CDbl(ws.Range("P5").Value)
                Case CDbl(ws.Range("Q5").Value)
                Case CDbl(ws.Range("R5").Value)
                Case CDbl(ws.Range("L7").Value)
                Case CDbl(ws.Range("M7").Value)
                Case CDbl(ws.Range("N7").Value)
                Case CDbl(ws.Range("O7").Value)
                Case CDbl(ws.Range("P7").Value)
                Case Else
                    NewColor = 3
            End Select
        Else
            NewColor = xlNone
        End If
        cell.Interior.ColorIndex = NewColor
        NewColor = xlNone
    Next cell
End If
Application.EnableEvents = True
```

This way, we force the input value to be a Double and we force the checked value to be a Double. The CDBL will happily take a string like `"1234"` and will convert it to `1234`. In the case of your needs, it will ensure both the input value, and the checked value are able to match.

The macro then runs just fine.

Comment: The code doesn't highlight values outside of the cases.

Comment: @Sid.T. Then something is wrong on your end. On my end, it highlights the values every time. Further, the logic behind the code would highlight values outside of the given range. You'll need to figure out how to debug this one on your own. I'm doing you no good by holding your hand every step of the way.